# How does report viewer work?

Tags: telerik-reporting

```
$reportViewer = $("#reportViewer1")
.telerik_ReportViewer({
serviceUrl: "/api/reports/",
templateUrl: '/ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
reportSource: { report: "MyClassLib.Group, MyClassLib" },
viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewMode.Interactive,
scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
scale: 1.0,
PersistSession: false
});
```

I took this code part from a sample project and modified only the reportSource. It was working but i didn't know how. I have tried to add reporting parameters, but problems started to show itself. Parameters not shown in parameter area in browser view although shown in design view.

1. I wonder especially, how serviceUrl is working and where is
   `/api/reports/` ?
2. I would appreciate, if you tell what other parameters is for and how
   they are working or give link of a document.

Comment: Can you post exact error you are getting? So folks here have a clue to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all client-side properties explained [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-jquery-fn-telerik-reportviewer.html).

Or you can look up

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/html5-report-viewer-embedding.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-implementing-http-service.html